# Customize Button of Android DatePicker

Tags: android, datepicker, customization

My current method to customize my UI is using the usual android DatePicker then use DatePicketDialog.getDatePicker() to get the inside component out, and customize it.

Now the result is in the image at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3286004/Screen%20Shot%202557-08-29%20at%202.52.21%20AM.png

The Question is ... I want to customize the black line above the DONE button to another color.
Could you suggest how I can get that line component out, so I can change it.

Thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely possible, actually you could do whatever you want with it. Really, one of options is to use style and theme which however would not work in 4.x. The more, lets say, proper or easy way is to use views itself like following:

```
        // we need this listener since only here all views are really drawn and accessible
        yourDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            private boolean areButtonsFixed;
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                if (areButtonsFixed)
                    return;

                // both buttons - you could search for only positive button or whatever button your dialog has
                final Button btnPositive = getButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                final Button btnNegative = getButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
                final Button btnNeutral = getButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);

                // buttons layout parameters, change it into material style (gravity right)
                final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnPositive.getLayoutParams();
                lp.weight = 0; // was 1 to fill 50% horizontally

                // positive button, set your own label
                btnPositive.setText(R.string.dialog_ok_label);
                // set text color and size                
btnPositive.setTextColor(ResHelper.getColor(R.color.blue_bright));
                btnPositive.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, ResHelper.getDimensPx(R.dimen.text_size_14));

                btnPositive.setLayoutParams(lp);

                // divider above buttons
                ((LinearLayout) btnPositive.getParent().getParent()).setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_NONE);
                areButtonsFixed = true;
}
```

This (prelast line) will remove divider above buttons at all. If you wish to customize it instead do it like following:

```
((LinearLayout) btnPositive.getParent().getParent()).setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.yer_drawable);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use another theme. This theme is Holo i think, so you can't change colors.

I think you can create your dialog with a custom layout.
If you used a custom layout, you can change colors.

Or, you should use another theme, or create your own theme.

**EDIT**

Yep, at run-time too. 
Many things using on your layout are locked, like colors, especially on widgets (searchView for example)

Comment: Just to confirm, even if I can do it in run-time programmatically?
I feel that I just cannot find how to access that component. 

Anyway, I will try make a theme to day and confirm the result, Thanks alot :D

Answer (score 0):

In default dialog it is impossible, this line has system color. You should convert this dialog to activity, then you can change color there.